# How to test whether a given set of data possesses serial dependence or not?

Tags: time-series, iid

I have a dataset where there are measurements taken over time. I have no assumptions whatsoever regarding the exact nature of the process, i.e. whether the measurements are iid or belong to a time series. I do know that I can test for autocorrelations (e.g. using Ljung-Box test) or plot autocorrelation plots as a sort of an eyeball test, but as far as I know these statistics are mostly looking at linear relationships. If there are no linear relationships, we take it as independence of consecutive data points, but this is not necessarily true for distributions other than the normal distribution.

In general, is the lack of linear relationships between lagged values an indicator of independence in time series? If not, is there a measure (such as mutual information for non-time series datasets) to check serial dependence?

Thanks in advance.